# TYPO3: Extend sys_file_metadata with new FAL image? Multiple FileProcessors?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I extended sys_file_metadata with an new FAL-Object "teaserimages".
TCA, Model, Database etc. everything in the Backend is working, but when I access the new property in Fluid like this:

```
file.properties.teaserimages
```

It returns an Int (the count of the FAL-Images).

As I need the new property for "Uploads" I tried to extend the tt_content.uploads Typoscript:

```
tt_content.uploads = < lib.contentElement
tt_content.uploads {
templateName = Uploads
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
        references.fieldName = media
        as = myfiles # Returns all Files as "myfiles"

        dataProcessing {                
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            20 {
                 references.fieldName = teaserimages
                 as = teaserimages
            }
         }
    }
}
```

So I thougt I could interate all "myfiles" an then, via a second file processor, all the "teaserimages" of all files, but somehow this doesnt work out. Can I only combine DatabaseQueryProcessor in each other, or DatabaseQueryProcessor and within that an FilesProcessor?

Or is there another way to read the teaserimages?

Answer (score 0):

You did something wrong in your typoscript.

Here is the correct way to do this :

```
tt_content.uploads =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.uploads {
  templateName = Uploads
  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
      references.fieldName = media
      as = myfiles # Returns all Files as "myfiles"
    }

    20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    20 {
      references.fieldName = teaserimages
      as = teaserimages
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesnt work in my case. I extended sys_file_metadata, so I need a DataProcessor for the file.properties, like

#1: get the files itself
#2: get the teaserimages from #1

Comment: Mmh ok have you tried the FalViewHelper from bootstrap_package then? It can be used like this in your template : `<bk2k:fal table="sys_file_metadata" data="{data}" field="teaserimages" as "teaserimages">`. This will add a variable called teaserimages which should contain your data.

Comment: Thank you! bk2k:fal didnt work in my case because the uid handling differs to normal elements but I found a (hacky) workaround via an own VH. at least bk2k:fal was a good kickstart :-)

Comment: Ok maybe you can post your VH code here to help the next person that will have the same issue.

Comment: Sure, but be warned that this is not the best code :-D https://pastebin.com/qGzwpZPd